# autoload em classes usando mvc

Tags: php, mvc

### Tem como fazer isto em php

```
use COntroller;
class Bootstrapp(){

public static function logar(){
$controller=new \Controller\$controlador();
}
```

jã tentei aqui e da erro de sintaxi

aqui em baixo o codigo

```
if (is_readable($caminho)) {

            require $caminho;
            $controlador = ucfirst($controller);
           ( $controller = new \controllers\$controlador;) aqui onde da erro

            if (is_callable(array($controller, $metodo))) {

                $metodo = $pedido->getMetodo();
            } else {
                $metodo = "index";
            }

            if (isset($parametro)) {
                call_user_func_array(array($controller, $metodo), $parametro);
            } else {
                call_user_func(array($controller, $metodo));
            }
        } else {
            header("Location:" . URL . "error");
        }
```

Comment: E o que tentas te fazer? Podes colocar o código?

Comment: Tem coisa errada nesse "MVC", *logar* não deve ser um método de bootstrap! Login é uma requisição do usuário e precisa de lógica (model), logo deve ser um *controller*.

Comment: MVC não tem nada a ver com autoload do php.. acho que o que vc quer é fazer autoload de classes com namespace. Primeiramente procure entender os padrões para autoload, veja isso: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/

Comment: Li a pergunta cinco vezes e não entendi o que é que você está tentando fazer. Entretanto, o PHP diferencia maiúsculas de minúsculas no nome de variáveis, e portaanto `Controller`, `COntroller` e `controller` são coisas diferentes. Além disso, eu acho que `new \Controller\$controlador();` e `new \controllers\$controlador;` não são sintaxes válidas.

Answer (score 2):

Bom, eu uso essa função.  Ela é usada da seguinte forma:

a função abaixo vai no arquivo autoload.php

```
function funcaoCarregadora($ClassName){
    $pasta = ultimaPalavra($ClassName);
    include_once($pasta."/".$ClassName.".php");

}

function ultimaPalavra($string){
    $tmp = '';
    $char = '';
    for($i = strlen($string)-1; $i >= 0 ; --$i){
        $char = $string[$i];
        $tmp .= $char;
        if(ctype_upper($char)){
                break;
        }
    }

    return strrev($tmp);
}
```

daí no arquivo config.php dou um include do autoload.php

include_once('autoload.php');

o config.php, tem a função de segurança e redirecionamento.

e em todas as páginas eu dou um include do config.php

include_once('config.php');

e abaixo desse includ eu instancio minhas classes

pronto.

Espero ter ajudado!

Obs.: minhas classes são nomeadas da seguinte forma:

Arquivo

MinhaClasseDao.php

classe

MinhaClasseDao
MinhaClasseModel
MinhaClasseController

e a View pode ser qualquer nome...

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 1):

Revirei o Google e encontrei a Solucção

```
 if (is_readable($caminho)) {

            require $caminho;
            $controlador = ucfirst($controller);
//Adicionei a linha abaixo
      $namespace = "\\" . "controllers" . "\\" . $controlador; 
            $controller = new $namespace;

            if (is_callable(array($controller, $metodo))) {

                $metodo = $pedido->getMetodo();
            } else {
                $metodo = "index";
            }

            if (isset($parametro)) {
                call_user_func_array(array($controller, $metodo), $parametro);
            } else {
                call_user_func(array($controller, $metodo));
            }
        } else {
            header("Location:" . URL . "error");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sua pergunta e resposta não parecem compor om código OOP, se puder ampliar o exemplo eu posso dar resposta mais ampla, mas por ora, acho que esse exemplo pode ajuar.

Você pode criar um autoload simples. Usei [`stream_resolve_include_path`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.stream-resolve-include-path.php) para verificar se o aruivo existe antes de importar.

```
spl_autoload_register( function( $file )
{
    if( stream_resolve_include_path( "{$file}.php" ) === false )
    throw new Exceptions( "O arquivo `{$file}` não existe." );

    include "{$file}.php";
});
```